# Is it possible to add CheckBoxcolumn only at certain rows in a datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I will have my data grid view as follows

```
 RecordTypeCode   Content
   FileHeader      1111111111111
   BatchHeader     5666666666666
   EntryDetail     656546545644545
   BatchControl    8654654564564
   FileControl     945645
```

I would like to have check boxes only at BatchHeader and EntryDetail is it possible. This is the way i am binding data to data grid view

```
 if (line.StartsWith("1"))
{
  dcID = new DataColumn("RecordTypeCode");
  dt.Columns.Add(dcID);
  DataColumn dcSomeText = new DataColumn("Content");
  dt.Columns.Add(dcSomeText);
  dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["RecordTypeCode"] = filecontrolvariables.rectype[line.Substring(0, 1)].ToString();
  dr["Content"] = line;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

if (line.StartsWith("5"))
{
   dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["RecordTypeCode"] = filecontrolvariables.rectype[line.Substring(0, 1)].ToString();
  dr["Content"] = line;
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

I would like to add check boxes as per needed can any one help me

I tried this

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
{
  if (dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RecordTypeCode"].Value.ToString() == "BatchHeader")
 {
    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
     e.Handled = true;
  }
 }
```

Sample image when my data binded

[image]

I tried this

```
 int columnIndex = -1;
 int rowIndex = -1;
 if (dataGridView2.CurrentCell != null)
 {
     columnIndex = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
     rowIndex = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
  }
   if (columnIndex == 0)
   {
     if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
    if (dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RecordTypeCode"].Value.ToString() == "Batch Header")
    {
      e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
      e.Handled = true;
     }
     }
   }
```

But my corresponding row is showing empty when i check it only for BatchHeader

Comment: Do you mean that you want a checkbox for only certain rows in a datagridview: batchheader and entrydetail?

Comment: In that case I think a better title to this question would be `Is it possible to add checkboxes only at certain rows in datagridview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the cellpainting event to not display the checkbox at all. I'm not sure if this would have other consquences during data binding but it did not display the checkbox for the rows that I wanted.

I have updated the method for what you would need.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
            {
                //if (e.ColumnIndex == <index of your checkbox column> && (e.RowIndex == 1 || e.RowIndex == 2))
                if (dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RecordTypeCode"].Value.ToString() == "Batch Header" && e.ColumnIndex == <index of your checkbox column should be 0 sicne its the first column>)
                {
                    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

The condition for `e.RowIndex == 1 || e.RowIndex == 2` is based on the fact that batchheader and entrydetail wont change their position. But if that is dynamic, then you can just check the text in the recordtype column to match BatchHeader and EntryDetail.

The if statement is the most important, it checks which particular cell (row, column) is the one you dont want any checkbox in. They must be used with an AND (&&) as you want one particular cell. You can use the code I have written as is if what you have explained is what you need. You will probably need to add one more check in the if statement for entry detail which needs to be done with an OR (||) with the batch header check. Exactly how I have in the commented part of the code, taking notice to the brackets especially.

I saw the solution at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/61507/How-to-hide-CheckBox-for-particular-cell-in-Datagr) which worked when I tried it. There are others mentioned incase this isn't suitable for what you want.

Comment: How can i match the text as per you said as my data is dynamic

Comment: You can check whether the text value in a particular cell is equal to the text u want. datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RecordTypeCode"].Value == "BatchHeader". I think you may have to first cast it to string and it maybe better to use the String.Equals method

Comment: Can you check my edits and tell whether it is correct. But still it is showing check box for every row

Comment: yes that is because your condition is incomplete... see the condition that i have put in my code. Firstly you are missing the check for the checkboxcolumn. Secondly you have the condition only for batch header.

Comment: you only have specified the row... think about this as the grid, if you want to specify one particular cell, you need a row and a column index. Right now you are checking only the row. Where is the column check? I have written it in my code, and I am updating my code for what you want.

Comment: Also, I hope you have actually added the cellpainting event to the grid!